# Ionic 2: navigate using URLs

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am very new in Ionic 2 framework. I would like to know, how can I navigate in ionic app using urls. Similar way as navigation is done in Angular 2 application.

Let's say I want to have **IntroPage** on **localhost:8100/intro** with login button and after pressing the button I want to be redirect to **HomePage** on **localhost:8100/home**.

```
localhost:8100/intro -> localhost:8100/home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DeepLinker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/DeepLinker/) of ionic2.

In ionic2, you can navigate just with `this.navigator.push(SomeComponent)`. But if you want the url change, you need define deeplinker for them like:

```
imports: [
 IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {
  links: [
   { component: HomePage, name: 'Home', segment: 'home' }
  ]
 })
]
```

Answer (score 0):

as documentation says : (`https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/`)
you cannot still use ui-sref like in ionic 1..but only this.navigation.push('home')... it means you have to do a function on a html (maybe a (click)="myfunc()" ) to call the navigation in ts file

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
   template: '<ion-nav #myNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>'
})
export class MyApp {
   @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController
   public rootPage = TabsPage;

   // Wait for the components in MyApp's template to be initialized
   // In this case, we are waiting for the Nav with reference variable of "#myNav"
   ngOnInit() {
      // Let's navigate from TabsPage to Page1
      this.nav.push('home');
   }
}
```